# webpack-dev-server hot reload not working

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack, vue.js

My file structure is:

```
dist
  css
    style.css
  index.html
  js
    bundle.js
src
  css
    style.css
  index.html
  js
    main.js
node_modules
webpack.config.js
package.json
```

My webpack.config.js looks like:

```
module.exports = {
    entry: './src/js/main.js',
    output: {
        path: __dirname,
        filename: './dist/js/bundle.js'
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                exclude: /(node_modules)/,
                loader: 'babel',
                query: {
                    presets: ['es2015']
                }
            },
            {
                test: /\.vue$/,
                loader: 'vue'
            }
        ]
    }
};
```

I run:

```
webpack-dev-server --content-base dist --hot
```

And it builds and seems like it's working. localhost:8080 shows the expected result but hot-reload does just not work. When I change a file I can see in terminal that a rebuild is happening but nothing happens in the browser. Am I missing something in the config?

Comment: Half the answers below don't work in webpack 5 (they use obsolete options) and none of them work for me. webpack has some of the worst backwards compatibility and documentation of any major open source project I've used.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

When using `webpack-dev-server`, it builds all files internally and *does not* spit them out into your output path. Running `webpack` alone, without the dev server, does the actual compilation to disk. The dev server does everything in memory which speeds up re-compilation by a lot.

To fix your hot reload issue, set the content base to your source directory and enable [inline-mode](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/#devserverinline)

Like so:

```
webpack-dev-server --content-base src --hot --inline
```

Comment: I don't understand. So wheres the index.html that adds a script with bundle.js or how does this work? If it point to source I'd get my app's folder structure at localhost:8080

Comment: @JuanSolano, the `<script>` tag can be injected by webpack into your existing html or you can generate an html from a template. To give you a proper answer, I suggest you ask a question with your specific setup; i'd be glad to help!

Comment: Or, in webpack.config.js modify the devServer  node to include both   {inline:true, hot: true} ?

Comment: always had issues with this and had content-base as dist when it should of been src! thanks.

Comment: `inline` is no longer an option in webpack 5. webpack has the worst documentation and backwards compatibility of any major open source project I've used.

Answer (score 38):

What worked for me is to write `<script src="bundle.js">` and not `<script src="dist/bundle.js">` in my `index.html` file.

```
// index.html
<script src="bundle.js"></script>      // works
<script src="dist/bundle.js"></script> // doesn't work!
```

Keeping `dist/bundle.js` as the output file works perfectly fine if you just build it using `webpack`. But when using `webpack-dev-server`, the static file already in the file system continues to be served, and not the latest hot replacement. It seems `webpack-dev-server` gets confused when it sees `dist/bundle.js` in the html file and doesn't hot replace it, even though `webpack.config.js` is configured to that path.

Comment: this work for me too. I can see following message on start

ℹ ｢wds｣: Project is running at http://localhost:8080/
ℹ ｢wds｣: webpack output is served from /

Comment: Helped me as well. It doesn't makes any sense to me tho.. Thanks!

Comment: This was the final solution for me. I just wished I had stumbled on this earlier, I would have saved a day of failed attempts.

Comment: this is not good answer. If you do like this answer, you have to rename the filename every time. instead, you have to set `publicPath` option. `output: { publicPath:"/dist", ... }`. see Jay Bidwai's answer below. https://stackoverflow.com/a/51762971/10587221

Answer (score 12):

None of the options on this page worked for me. After changing the devServer section to:

```
devServer: {
    port: 8080,
    contentBase: ['./src', './public'], // both src and output dirs
    inline: true,
    hot: true
},
```

it worked.

Comment: Thank you, been searching for 2 hours and this answer solved it after countless blogs and comments, upvoted!

Comment: The `inline` and `contentBase` options no longer exist in webpack 5 :'(

Comment: webpack has some of the worst documentation and backwards compatibility of any major open source project I've used.

Answer (score 6):

**For Webpack ^5.72.1**

This worked for me,

```
 devServer: {
    port: 3000,
    hot: false,
    liveReload: true,
  },
```

Note: liveReload will reload the whole application on file save but it will lose application state. Hot reloading preserves state. But liveReload seemed to fix the issue for me with css/html not loading on the browser after save, without having to refresh the browser.

Comment: Unfortunately, this didn't work for me (webpack 5.76.2). As an aside, webpack has some of the worst documentation of any major open source project I've used.

Answer (score 2):

--inline --hot wasn't an issue for me

If you are using redux can try this.

For some random reason `redux-devtools` was not allowing hot reload for me. Try removing it from root component and `redux compose` config.

Note: Use redux devtool browser extension with this config in your store configuration: `window.devToolsExtension ? window.devToolsExtension() : f => f`

Also, must read: https://medium.com/@rajaraodv/webpacks-hmr-react-hot-loader-the-missing-manual-232336dc0d96#.ejpsmve8f

Or try hot reload 3: 
example: https://github.com/gaearon/redux-devtools/commit/64f58b7010a1b2a71ad16716eb37ac1031f93915

Answer (score 2):

Webpack hot reloading stopped working for me as well. The solution for me was to delete the `node_modules` folder and fresh install all dependencies. 
Just open the parent folder of `node_modules` in your terminal and run `npm install`

Answer (score 2):

**100% Working Solution**

You have to just follow 3 steps and you will get your hot reloading as you expected

1. Include "publicPath" key in "Output" property of webpack config. "publicPath" should contain path to your bundle.js file so that dev-server will know if there is any change in your bundle.js file and it will reload your application.

Your config should look like this -

> ```
> output: {
>    path: __dirname,
>    publicPath:"/dist/js/",
>    filename: './dist/js/bundle.js'
> }
> ```

2. Add "devServer" option in config file -

> ```
> devServer:{
>    contentBase:"/src/",
>    inline:true,
>    stats:"errors-only"
> }
> ```

Please note that **contentBase** should point to the path where you put your index.html file which contain your script tag in your case it will be "/src/"

3. At last you have to make sure 'src' attribute of your 'script' tag in index.html points to bundle.js starting from "http://localhost:port" as follow -

> `<script src="http://localhost:portnumber + value in publicPath + bundle.js"></script>`

in your case it will look like this -

```
<script src="http://localhost:8080/js/dist/bundle.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

And finally remember `webpack-dev-server doesn't compile your js file or make build or watch on your js` file it dose everything in memory to watch on your js file you have to run
`webpack --watch`
in seprate window

Comment: I'm using webpack 5.76.2, and the `inline` and `contentBase` options no longer exist. webpack changes its API more than a fashion model changes clothes... ;'(

Answer (score 2):

The only thing that works for me is apply the "[hotOnly](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/#devserverhotonly)" inside the configuration of the "devServer" (on the "webpack.config.js"), like this:

```
devServer: {
    hotOnly: true,
},
```

After reload the "Webpack Dev Server", the "Hot Reload" works, at least, after saving any change in CSS or JS files.

Comment: I'm using webpack 5.76.2, and there is no `hotOnly` option. webpack changes its API more than a fashion model changes clothes...

Answer (score 2):

All those who suffer: don’t forget slash before public path:
`publicPath:’/assets/scripts/‘`  not `publicPath:’assets/scripts/’`
Three days lost because of 1 forward slash in the path string

Comment: I'm guessing you used `publicPath` on the output, is that right?  Isn't the output for building the project out to a `dist` folder per se to deploy to prod?   Or did you use `publicPath` in the `entry`?

Answer (score 1):

I increased the max number of file changes that can be watched and it worked for me. I guess the issue for me was too many files.

```
echo fs.inotify.max_user_watches=1999999 | sudo tee -a /etc/sysctl.conf && sudo sysctl -p
```

[source](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/444998/how-to-set-and-understand-fs-notify-max-user-watches)

Comment: Nice, only one that worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

In your `package.json` file, delete the line that contains `"test" "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"` under the scripts object, and replace it with:

```
...
"scripts": {
    "start": "webpack-dev-server --hot"
  },

...
```

Then to restart your project, just use `npm start`.

This worked for me when I ran into this problem.

Edit: Can you share your `package.json` file?

Try adding this to webpack.config.js as well

```
devServer: {
  inline: true,
  port: 3000,
  hot: true
},
```

Comment: I run the dev server directly from CLI instead of using an npm script, which shouldn't make a difference at all... I think it has to do with my file structure and I might not be using --content-base param correctly

Comment: Why would you delete the test stub?

Answer (score 0):

Check your console logs if it has below error then add cors to your webpack dev server file

```
No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin react hot reload
```

Ideally add below entry in you dev server js

```
headers: { "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*" },
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try adding this to your config:

```js
module.exports = {
...
  devServer: {
    contentBase: './dist/', // Since your index.html is in the "dist" dir
    open: true,             // Automatically open the browser
    hot: true,              // Automatically refresh the page whenever bundle.js changes
                            // (You will have to refresh manually if other files change)
  },
...
};
```

And then running (no options):
`webpack-dev-server`

Comment: I'm using webpack 5.76.2, and there is no longer a `contentBase` option. webpack changes its API more than a fashion model changes clothes... ;'(

Answer (score 0):

With the above settings, while using `webpack-dev-server` for static page building I add bundle js or whatever js file configured as output to the html page. This way I get refresh on my static page after any changes.

Answer (score 0):

For webpack version 5, the module.loaders is now module.rules. And for the presets change query to options.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32132023)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure in development mode you are not using a plugin that extract css into files, example MiniCssExtractPlugin. It messes the things up.

Answer (score 0):

#### Webpack ^5.90.3

In your Webpack config JS you need to set the `devServer.hot` property to `true`:

```javascript
module.exports = {

    devServer: {
        hot: true,
    },

...
```

[Webpack Documentation - Configuration - devServer.hot](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/#devserverhot)