# Should Webpack's dev-server have the src or dist folder as content base?

Tags: javascript, webpack, hot-reload

I've been troubleshooting an issue with Webpack all day and finally fixed it. But now I'd like *why* it works and the processes behind. For starters here's a quick look at my webpack.config.js:

```
const path = require('path');
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require('mini-css-extract-plugin');
const webpack = require('webpack');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
    mode: 'development',
    entry: {
        checkout: './src/checkout_1.js'
    },
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
        filename: 'js/[name].js'
    },
    plugins: [
        new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
            publicPath: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
            filename: 'css/[name].css',
        }),
        new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
           // hash: true,
            template: './src/checkout_1.html',
            filename: 'index.html',
            chunks: ['checkout']
        })
    ],
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                use: [
                    'css-hot-loader',
                    {
                        loader: MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
                        options: {
                            publicPath: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist/css'),
                            //filename: '[name].css',
                        }
                    },
                    'css-loader'/*,
                    'style-loader'*/
                ]
            },
            {
                test: /\.html$/,
                use: [
                    {
                        loader: 'html-loader',
                        options: {
                            interpolate: true,
                            name:'[name].html',
                            publicPath: '/'
                        }
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                test: /\.(png|svg|jpg|gif)$/,
                use: [
                    {
                        loader: 'file-loader',
                        options: {
                            name:'img/[name].[ext]',
                            publicPath: '/'
                        }
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                test: /\.(ttf|eot|svg|woff|woff2|otf)$/,
                use:[
                    {
                        loader: 'file-loader',
                        options: {
                            name:'fonts/[name].otf',
                            publicPath: '/'
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    devServer: {
        contentBase: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src'), // This was set to "dist," which was causing the issue
        hot: true,
        publicPath: '/',
        inline: true,
        watchContentBase: true
    }
};
```

Initially, the `contentBase` parameter was set to `path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist')`

Then the issue would be that the HMR wouldn't work properly: updating any CSS file would hot reload the page, but the changes on the HTML side wouldn't be applied unless I manually refreshed the page. The code would still get recompiled according to the console, and I would see in the browser's log messages that a change had been detected and it would attempt a hot reload before saying "nothing hot updated."

I changed `dist` to `src` and now all changes trigger a hot reload. I'm happy that it works but I don't quite understand the mechanics behind. I've found out that the dev web server doesn't actually write to the disk, but only compiles the files in memory, which allows it to be faster. However, I can see that it still generates some files like the CSS and image files. Also, according to the documentation, the "contentBase" attribute refers to "where the content is served from." Logically, the content is served from the "dist" folder, right?

I'm a bit confused with all this so I'd need a bit of theory to fully grasp the concept. Thanks

Comment: Afaik, during development, where HMR is used, you're editing the files in `src` so it makes sense that **dev**Server cares about `src`, not `dist` (which is where the final, built application ends up). See here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39067341/5734311

Comment: I get that but then why is some of the content, like the CSS, refreshed and not the HTML?

Comment: Could you show your file/folder structure in src and dist? Or even better: Provide a minimal example to make it more comprehensible.