# webpack-dev-server hot reload is not working with webpack4

Tags: webpack-hmr

I have followed this [guide](https://webpack.js.org/guides/hot-module-replacement/#enabling-hmr) to config webpack hmr, but it does full reload. When I add `hotOnly` option to `true`, page is not doing full reload or partail reload, but I can see a request `main.1a4a7c39c73281101038.hot-update.js` is getting sent in console.

I have looked at this question: [webpack-dev-server hot reload not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39066298/webpack-dev-server-hot-reload-not-working) and can't solve my problem.

webpack.config.js

```
devServer: {
    port: 15000,
    hot: true,
    contentBase: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    watchContentBase: true
  }
```

package.json

```
"scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "build": "webpack --mode production",
    "start": "webpack-dev-server"
  },
"devDependencies": {
    "clean-webpack-plugin": "^3.0.0",
    "css-loader": "^4.2.0",
    "file-loader": "^6.0.0",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^4.3.0",
    "style-loader": "^1.2.1",
    "webpack": "^4.44.1",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.3.12",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.11.0"
  }
```

You can checkout this demo on [github](https://github.com/kanbekotori/webpack-dev-server)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [watchOptions](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/#devserverwatchoptions-)

```
watchOptions: {
  poll: true,
  ignored: '/node_modules/',
},
```

"hot" option is by default on, so don't need it.
"watchContentBase" is also true by default.

Comment: some computers dont need this code to run but some ones need, I dont know why